# How to dynamically add new values to existing array in javascript (Update value in ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am newbie at React js and i got some issue with this situation,
i have an array that i load from my DB , for this example take a look over "fields" array:

```
  componentDidMount()
    {
    axios.get('http://localhost:2000/form/'+this.props.match.params.id).then(response =>{
        this.setState({
            formname:response.data.formname,
            fields:response.data.fields
            })
         })
      .catch(function(error){
        })
    }
```

the content of "fields" array:

```
fields: Array(5)
0: (2) ["First name:", "text"]
1: (2) ["Last name:", "text"]
2: (2) ["Date of birth:", "date"]
3: (2) ["Email:", "email"]
4: (2) ["CV:", "file"]
```

now, i have a page and i want that every value that i insert to some field , will added to sub array of the main array ("fields"

so if i have First name field , and i insert "Michael" i want "Michael" be add to
first cell and its looks like:

```
fields: Array(5)
    0: (2) ["First name:", "text","Michael"]
    1: (2) ["Last name:", "text"]
    2: (2) ["Date of birth:", "date"]
    3: (2) ["Email:", "email"]
    4: (2) ["CV:", "file"]
```

i tried something in my handleChange 
but i think its absoulty wrong..

```
handleChange(e)
    {
        this.setState({fields:[...this.state.fields,e.target.value]})
    }
```

So how can i add more values to this existing array?
Thank you

Comment: Please share a [mre]. The syntax of your example `array` is not valid, which makes understanding your question that much harder. Show an example of what exactly is in `fields` before you set state, and what you want it to be after you set state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### If you simply want to update all values with that "key".

this will overwrite any value that has this "key" event if there are multiple entries.

```
function handleChange(fieldName, value) {
    const fields = state.fields.map(_ => {
        if (_[0] === fieldName) _[1] = value;
        return _;
    });
    this.setState({fields});
}
```

Important to note is that I create a new array with map and set that to the state so react notices the change.

*Hint:*
You might want to use an object for this so you could go:

```
function handleFirstNameChange(firstName) {
    this.setState({firstName})
}

function handleLastNameChange(lastName) {
    this.setState({lastName})
}
```

A class component would look something like:

```
class SomeForm extends React.Component {
    state = {
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
    }

    constructor() {
        // ====================================================================
        // THESE LINES ARE IMPORTANT IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHY ASK!!
        // ====================================================================
        this.onFirstNameChange = this.onFirstNameChange.bind(this);
        this.onLastNameChange = this.onLastNameChange.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input
                    value={this.state.firstName}
                    onChange={this.onFirstNameChange}
                />
                <input
                    value={this.state.lastName}
                    onChange={this.onLstNameChange}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }

    onFirstNameChange(firstName) {
        this.setState({firstName});
    }
    onLstNameChange(firstName) {
        this.setState({firstName});
    }
}
```

The type of the state would then look something like this (this is typescript which is basically used to describe how objects and friends look and behave):

```
state: {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    [... and so on ...]
}
```

instead of:

```
state: Array<[
    string, // First value is the key
    string, // Second value is the actual value
]>
```

I know that your API works differently but you just might wanna convert it for easier access in the interface... or don't :D it's up to you :)

(Or just convert them locally in the browser, modify them, convert them back and post them)

Answer (score 0):

*Edited since post updated.

If you have an array of arrays and want to add a value to the first array in that array. You'll need to edit it by index and use the push function.

If I think I understand the problem, I would implement the following in your handleChange function for an input box related to the first name field:

```
    handleChange(e) {
      let fields = this.state.fields;
      if(fields[0].length === 2){
        fields[0].push(e.target.value);  
      } else {
        fields[0][2] = (e.target.value);  
      }
      this.setState({fields});
    }
```

You shouldn't be mutating the state directly, that's why we set it to a variable in local context first. If we've already created a third value in the array, we don't want to keep pushing to the index and instead we want to replace the values being entered, hence the if statement here.

If I now type in Michael into an input box with this handleChange function, I see that the current state of fields is now:

```
fields: Array(5)
    0: (2) ["First name:", "text", "Michael"]
    1: (2) ["Last name:", "text"]
    2: (2) ["Date of birth:", "date"]
    3: (2) ["Email:", "email"]
    4: (2) ["CV:", "file"]
```

If you want to add more than one value to the same field from the same function, then I would recommend changing this code and perhaps having a submit button handle the logic rather than doing everything in handleChange. Please let me know if this helps or I misunderstood your required implementation.

Comment: yap , you understood me well but you showed me an example with index 0 but in my case i have 5 fields , for each field i insert new value and i want some logic that will inset the value to the spesific field, so for example if i type "Michael" in my First name field so i want "Michael" will insert to the first arrray, and if  write "Johnson" as last name so i want it will insert to second array.. thank you for your answer

Comment: Wouldn't it make way more sense if you use an object for that? Like: `{firstName: "Michael", lastName: "Jackson"}`. Or a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: Do you have different input boxes for each field? If this is the case, you can have separate handleChange functions for each input box.. or just make the handleChange function take a parameter which references the index of the field that you're referring to.